# React Beautiful DND- Uncaught RbdInvariant {message: 'Invariant failed: Could not find required context'}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a component in React that uses react-beautiful-dnd. This component renders a list of items that can be dragged. Here is the code for this component-

```js
const LeftPanelForTables = (props: LeftPanelForTablesProps) => {
    const { items } = props;
    return items.map((item: any, index: number) => (
        <Draggable
            key={item.id}
            draggableId={item.id}
            index={index}
        >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <div
                    className={cx(styles.table)}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                >
                    <div className={cx(styles.table_parent)}>
                        <Typography
                            variant={'p'}
                            className={styles.tableText}
                        >
                            {item.name}
                        </Typography>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    ));
};

export default LeftPanelForTables;
```

This code runs properly without any error and produces the desired output.
Now I am writing a unit test for this code.

```js
describe('LeftPanelForTables', () => {
    const items = [
        { id: '1', name: 'Table 1', isSelected: false },
        { id: '2', name: 'Table 2', isSelected: true },
    ];

    it('renders the table items correctly', () => {
        const { container, getByText } = render(
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={(result:DropResult)=>{}}>
                <LeftPanelForTables items={items} />
            </DragDropContext>
        );

        // Check if both table names are rendered
        expect(getByText('Table 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(getByText('Table 2')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

The test fails with below error-
**Error: Uncaught [Error: Error: Uncaught RbdInvariant {
message: 'Invariant failed: Could not find required context'
}**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my test file, I had to wrap the `<LeftPanelForTables>` component within `<Droppable>` imported from react-beautiful-dnd.

Here is a gif that explains the component hierarchy in react-beautiful-dnd-
[image: component hierarchy in rbd]

In my code, since the `<LeftPanelForTables>` contains a `<Draggable>`, we need to wrap it inside a `<Droppable>` and the `<Droppable>` should be wrapped inside `<DragDropContext>`.
So here is my new test file-

```js
describe('LeftPanelForTables', () => {
    const items = [
        { id: '1', name: 'Table 1', isSelected: false },
        { id: '2', name: 'Table 2', isSelected: true },
    ];

    it('renders the table items correctly', () => {
        const { container, getByText } = render(
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={(result:DropResult)=>{}}>
                <Droppable droppableId="droppable" isDropDisabled={true}>
                    {(provided: any, snapshot: any) => (
                        <div ref={provided.innerRef}>
                            <LeftPanelForTables items={items} />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
        );

        // Check if both table names are rendered
        expect(getByText('Table 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(getByText('Table 2')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```